# Unable to catch Sql Exception with persistent and `catch` function

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to run a `deleteWhere` query with Persistent, however sometimes this delete is unsuccessful due to foreign key violations (I don't want to trigger a cascading delete, I don't want users to be able to delete if the `Supplier` is used by other entities elsewhere in the system). Going off this https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Handling-Persistence-Exception.md it looks like I am fine to use `catch` from `Control.Monad.Catch`.

```
import           Control.Monad.Catch
import qualified Database.Persist as P
import           Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Errors (ConstraintViolation(..))

data DeleteSupplierResult
  = DeleteSupplierSuccess
  | DeleteSupplierForeignKeyViolation
  | DeleteSupplierUncaughtError

deleteSupplier
  :: MonadCatch m
  => MonadIO m
  => Key Supplier
  -> SqlPersistT m DeleteSupplierResult
deleteSupplier sid =
  (DeleteSupplierSuccess <$ deleteSupplierByKey sid) `catch` (return . catchFailures)
  where
    catchFailures = \case
      ForeignKeyViolation _ _ ->
        DeleteSupplierForeignKeyViolation

      _ ->
        DeleteSupplierUncaughtError

deleteSupplierByKey :: MonadIO m => Key Supplier -> SqlPersistT m ()
deleteSupplierByKey key =
  P.deleteWhere [SupplierId P.==. key]
```

Is my issue that I am trying to match `ConstraintViolation` and this isn't the actual exception being thrown? How can I determine which error persistent is throwing and catch that?

Comment: Do not use `MonadCatch`, you are better of using [`unliftio`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.19/unliftio-0.2.10/UnliftIO-Exception.html)

Comment: @lehins, that's a bold statement. Is there a particular reason it's true in this context?

Comment: @dfeuer That does sound like a bold statement, but I didn't mean anything by it :) That being said, I did not write it without reason and it does deserve it's own SO question. But in short, there would be a problem if exception being caught was `SomeException` rather than `ConstraintViolation`, cause then async exceptions would get caught as well. In this particular context, @danbrooks can use `catchAny` from `unliftio` to safely catch all synchronous exceptions to figure out which exceptions is being thrown and handle it appropriately. MonadCatch on the other hand would not be safe.

Comment: @lehins, sadly, I'm pretty sure there *is no* entirely safe way to do that. It's just not possible (as far as I know) to reliably determine whether a caught exception was thrown synchronously (`throwIO`), asynchronously (`throwTo`), or imprecisely (`throw`). I really wish that gap in the interface were filled.

Comment: @dfeuer Maybe so, but there is much safer way to do it than what's done in `MonadCatch`. Eg.`asyncExceptionFromException` will tell you if the exception is designed to be an asynchronous one, but of course not that it was thrown asynchronously. At the same time `BlockedIndefinitely*` are not considered asynchronous, despite that they are thrown asynchronously.